# Autofill Date By Week

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to auto fill one cell to the right by week. For example A1 = 10-July
B1 = 17-July I want to auto fill C1 and C1 only to equal 24-July. My goal is to make it dynamic because I will be using it every week. My code below auto fills by day down the column. Thanks, Becca.

```
Sub Autofill()

Dim LR As Long

LR = Range("ZZ1").End(xlToLeft).Column

Range("A1").Autofill Destination:=Range("A1:A" & LR)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You want a DataSeries, not an AutoFill.

```
Sub Autofill()

    Dim LR As Long

    LR = Range("ZZ1").End(xlToLeft).Column
    cells(1, "A") = date(2018, 7, 10)
    Range(cells(1, "A"), cells(1, lr)).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlRows, Type:=xlChronological, Date:=xlDay, Step:=7, Trend:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but what exactly restrain you from using a simple formula in `B1` : `=A1+7` ?

Comment: Well I guess there is a presumption to be made, that the data can be so dynamic, that in the column it may not always contain specific dates. I don't think it's particularly the case here, but oh well... you never know. But yeah, most likely just people overcomplicating things while not utilizing basic excel functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Given you only want to fill one cell, `AutoFill` is not the right tool.  Also, calling your function the same thing as a built in method is a bad idea.

Note that this is implicitly working on the ActiveSheet (you may want to be more specific)

Try this

```
Sub MyAutofill()
    Dim LastFilledCell As Range

    Set LastFilledCell = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
    LastFilledCell.Offset(0, 1) = LastFilledCell.Value + 7
End Sub
```